# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext return FileNotFoundException exception when try to open beans xml file

Tags: java, spring

**i'v got an error exception :**

INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ma/openbook/www/beans/perons.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [ma/openbook/www/beans/perons.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ma/openbook/www/beans/perons.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

i did not understand wath should i do to resolve this issue, i though that's the code is correct
could someone help me please. i will be thankful

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d78ZK.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven, by default, does not move non-`.java` files from `/src/main/java` into the target build. Instead move your `persons.xml` resource to `/src/main/resource`, in the appropriate package.

Also, you seem to have a typo: `perons.xml` vs `persons.xml`.